# How to get more than 60 results for nearby places API

Tags: web-services, google-places-api, google-nearby

I am using google places API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch ) and looking to get more than 60 results. Presently, one call displays 20 results, and subsequent calls with next_token give up to 60 results. Is there a way to get more results through some other similar API or payment option?

Comment: Places API doesn't provide more results. You should understand that this API doesn't work as a database. The purpose is give you a list of most prominent places according to search parameters, but not a complete list of places.